# True or False question about continuous functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am working through my study guide for my calculus class for the test we're having tomorrow. There are two problems that I'm not completely sure about.

> For each of the following statements, determine whether it is true or false and justify your answer.
>
> 1. For any function $f:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, its image $f\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$ is an interval.
> 2. For any continuous function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, its image $f\left(D\right)$ is an interval.

For the first one, I said:

> False. Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{2}}$, $f$ is not continuous at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, and thus the image is not an interval.

For the second one, I said:

> False. If $D$ is not an interval.

For the first one, I am decently confident that my answer is correct. I would just like to know what you think, if it is sufficient enough.

However, for the second one, I don't know where to go for the second one. The professor would like an example, so maybe something like $D=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$? Because, then the image of $f(D)$ would not include 0, and thus not be an interval. Would that work as an example?

Comment: What part are you uncertain of? Is $f(x)=1/x$ continuous on $D$? Is $F(D)$ an interval? If you know the answers are "yes" and "no", then you know you have a counterexample.

Comment: Your answer to the first question is wrong, though. $f$ is not defined at $1/2$, so you haven't given a function with domain $[0,1]$ as required.

Comment: What is $D$? If $D$ is connected, then so is $f(D)$, thus $f(D)$ will be an interval. If $D$ is not then you can find a counterexample

Comment: Well, the reason why the image of $\,\frac{1}{x - 0.5}\,$ is not an interval is...because it is not. Someone could argue that the function isn't continuous at $\,0.5\,$ doesn't look sufficient, yet mentioning that the function has a vertical assymptote at $\,x=0.5\,$ is. Now just define $\,f(0.5)=-346.3434\,$ and you\re done. Your answer to second question is correct yet you must give an example, and you found a rathr nice one.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Ok, since f is not defined at $f(0.5)$, what else could I use to find something that has an image which is not an interval, but still defined everywhere in $[0,1]$? Maybe it would have something to do with continuity, since the problem does not say "continuous function"?

Comment: @Alex: That's entirely the wrong question to ask. Don't abandon your example because of a minor flaw! The function isn't defined at $0.5$, so just define it there. Make sure your definition doesn't cause the image to become an interval, and you're done.

Comment: Nevermind, @DonAntonio answered the question I was asking! Thank you, so simply setting a random value for $f(0.5)$ is sufficient to define it there, but still not be continuous.

Comment: No, there's one value of $f(0.5)$ that will *not* work. Can you see why?

Comment: Well, my first thought would be $\infty$ (if I could set a function value to $\infty$...), but after looking closer at the function, as $x$ gets closer to 0.5 from the negative side, it approaches $-\infty$, and $\infty$ from the positive side. Wouldn't any value that I set create a discontinuity between the positive and negative sides?

Comment: I think it's more helpful to learn to find easiest examples. You have one for 2 (Stefan above gives you the technical reason why it works, or can work); but your example for 1 (which can be made ok) is much too difficult. Recall that a function is just any functional relation between 2 spaces. Try something constant first. Here, mapping 0 to 1, and all other x in (0, 1] to 0 is a very easy counter you'll instantly see works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some easy counterexamples:

1. Define $$f(x) := \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right] \\ 1 & x \in \left(\frac{1}{2},1 \right] \end{cases}$$ Then $f([0,1]) = \{0,1\}$ and this is obviously no interval.
2. You already mentioned $g(x) := \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \in D:=(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$. That works. Another (maybe easier) one would be $$h(x) := x \qquad \qquad D=:[0,1] \cup [2,3]$$ Then $h(D)=[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ and this is -again- no interval (but $h$ is continuous).